# I cannot get SQL Server 2012 to install the database engine

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, clustering

SQL Server 2012 installation on a standard Windows 2008 R2 server. It refuses to install the database engine or sql replication.

During the installation I got no errors saying that it wasn't installing. So what I did was I ran a repair on the installation and it still stated it would not install. I'm afraid to uninstall and reinstall due to DTC being installed and I don't really want this to boil down to me doing a full 2008 reinstall.

Here's a screenshot of the error I'm getting with this after attempting a repair :

[image: screenshot]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated I've been banging my head on this for the past few days.

Also any suggestions on doing an uninstall/reinstall if need be would be great. I'm under the impression that it will cause issues though.

Comment: Can you post the contents of the setup log for the original install please, (Not the repair attempts)? You should find the log here `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log\`

Comment: I fixed the issue by uninstalling the database engine and then reinstalling it. Now it says it's running but I cannot connect to the database engine with the error of 

Cannot connect to SQL-1.

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\Log doesn't exist on the server

Comment: Are you attempting to connect locally or remotely?

Comment: Locally, on the same machine as Domain\Administrator

Comment: Can you tell me what protocols are enabled in SQL Server Configuration Manager? Thanks, MB

Answer (score 2):

SQL server 2012 installation is not supported through terminal services.  It causes a lot of strange problems, and I experienced this same issue.

Microsoft states this in their prerequisites:

Link is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx

This document states:

`The installation of SQL Server 2012 fails if you launch the setup through Terminal Services Client. Launching SQL Server Setup through Terminal Services Client is not supported.`

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a cluster install it differs a bit from a normal installation, and how you might go about troubleshooting it. SQL Server 2012 provides two options for doing a [cluster install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179530.aspx), which one did you pick?.

Is the installation failure you are referring to ocurring on your first node install or are you working on adding the second node?

Also if you have a successful install on the first node, and everything is online, when you try to connect you will need to use the cluster name that you configured for SQL Server, not the physical name of the node (SQL-1 or SQL-2). From your screenshot it appears you might want to use the Windows Cluster name "sqlcluster.mytrend.us" since I see "MSSQLSERVER" under the cluster service tree.

I have not done a full cluster install with SQL 2012 but you will need to verify that the TCP/IP protocol is configured properly. This may have occured during the cluster installation but you will want to verify it is enabled for the IP used by the SQL cluster resource.